plotly drop down menu map issues
Issues with my drop down menu. The values in the map don not match with the values I need them to match with. For example, if the drop down value is Number of deaths, the value in the map is death rate.The image should be showing the number of deaths for each countries, but is showing the death rate.

# three columns we're going to build choropleths from
cols = ['Number of Deaths', 'Death Rate Per 100,000']

# build figures for each of the required columns
# key technique is append a suffix to animation frame so each frame has it's
# own name...
figs = [
    px.choropleth(
        data_frame=Global_Burden_of_Disease_df_country,
        locations='Country Name',
        locationmode='country names',
        color=c,
        title='Choropleth Map Example',
        hover_name="Country Name",  # identify country code column
        animation_frame="Year",  # identify date column
        projection="equirectangular",  # select projection
        color_continuous_scale=color,  # select prefer color scale
    )
    for c, color in zip( cols, ["Blues", 'Reds'])
]


# play / pause don't work as don't stop between columns..
layout = {
    k: v
    for k, v in figs[0].to_dict()["layout"].items()
    if k not in ["template", "updatemenus"]
}


# build figure from all frames, with layout excluding play/pause buttons
fig = go.Figure(
    data=figs[0].data, frames=[fr for f in figs for fr in f.frames], layout=layout
)

# finally build drop down menu...
fig = fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "relayout",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "coloraxis": col_fig.layout.coloraxis,
                            "sliders": col_fig.layout.sliders,
                        }
                    ],
                }
                for c, col_fig in zip(cols, figs)
            ]
        }
    ]
)

fig

I am trying to create a map, that shows different values based on the year in the drop down menu. The values are from a dataframe.

I'm a little confused about your issue, is the image in your question hovering before you move the slider? When you move the slider, is it correct and does it not show up in the drop down items? I tried this with the example data in the reference. I'm just guessing here, but the initial graph may need to be set up with the data in each column as well.

I am using the image to show that the value shown does not correlate with the drop down menu. The image should be showing the number of deaths for each countries, but is showing the death rate. I am a beginner, so I am not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

You need to ensure update each time either dropdown values of slider values are chosen:
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Country Name": ["France", "Germany", "Sweden"] * 4,
    "Year": [2000, 2000, 2000, 2005, 2005, 2005, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2015, 2015, 2015],
    "Number of Deaths": [100, 150, 200, 110, 160, 210, 120, 170, 220, 130, 180, 230],
    "Death Rate Per 100,000": [10, 15, 20, 11, 16, 21, 12, 17, 22, 13, 18, 23],
}

Global_Burden_of_Disease_df_country = pd.DataFrame(data)

cols = ['Number of Deaths', 'Death Rate Per 100,000']

figs = []
frames = []

for c, color in zip(cols, ["Blues", 'Reds']):
    fig = px.choropleth(
        data_frame=Global_Burden_of_Disease_df_country,
        locations='Country Name',
        locationmode='country names',
        color=c,
        hover_name="Country Name",
        animation_frame="Year",
        projection="equirectangular",
        color_continuous_scale=color,
    )
    fig.update_layout(coloraxis_colorbar_title=c)
    figs.append(fig)
    
    for frame in fig.frames:
        frame['name'] = f"{c}_{frame['name']}"
        frames.append(frame)

layout = {
    k: v
    for k, v in figs[0].to_dict()["layout"].items()
    if k not in ["template", "updatemenus"]
}

fig = go.Figure(data=figs[0].data, layout=layout)
fig.frames = frames

frames_dict = {c: [f for f in frames if f['name'].startswith(c)] for c in cols}

dropdown_buttons = [
    {
        "label": c,
        "method": "animate",
        "args": [
            [f"{c}_{year}" for year in Global_Burden_of_Disease_df_country['Year'].unique()],
            {
                "mode": "immediate",
                "frame": {"duration": 500, "redraw": True},
                "transition": {"duration": 0},
            }
        ],
    }
    for c in cols
]

fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": dropdown_buttons,
            "direction": "down",
            "showactive": True,
        }
    ],
    coloraxis_colorbar_title=cols[0],  
    title={"text": f"Choropleth Map - {cols[0]}"}, 
)

fig.show()






Thank you so much. Do have any learning recommendations for plotly?

Search SO for solutions, try different approaches . I am an advocate of learning by doing.

Don't forget to markas accepted if it is what you were looking for so that it disappears from the list of unanswered questions happy coding!
